# How to get required custom WooCommerce checkout fields to stop checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My client requires 3 different parts to a Terms and Conditions agreement section before a customer can place an order. I've written the following code:

```
// in wptheme/functions.php

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_three_terms');

function add_three_terms ( $checkout ) {
  echo '<div id="terms_n_conditions"><h2>3. Agree to terms & conditions</h2>';
  echo "<h3>Member Agreement Part 1</h3>";
  echo "<p>...</p>";
  woocommerce_form_field ( 'agreement_one', array (
    "type"       => "checkbox",
    "label"      => __("I Agree"),
    "required" => true
  ), $checkout->get_value("agreement_one") );

  echo "<h3>Member Agreement Part 2</h3>";
  echo "<p>...</p>";
  woocommerce_form_field ( 'agreement_two', array (
    "type"       => "checkbox",
    "label"      => __("I Agree"),
    "required" => true
), $checkout->get_value("agreement_two") );

  echo "<h3>Member Agreement Part 3</h3>";
  echo "<p>...</p>";
  woocommerce_form_field ( 'agreement_three', array (
    "type"       => "checkbox",
    "label"      => __("I Agree"),
    "required" => true
), $checkout->get_value("agreement_three") );
  echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_function' );

function custom_checkout_function(){
  global $woocommerce;
  if( !isset($_POST['agreement_one']) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please agree to the Member Agreement Part 1' ), 'error' );
  }
  if( !isset($_POST['agreement_two']) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please agree to the Member Agreement Part 2' ), 'error' );
  }
  if( !isset($_POST['agreement_three']) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please agree to the Member Agreement Part 3' ), 'error' );
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_agreements_to_order_meta' );

function add_agreements_to_order_meta ( $order_id ) {
  if ( ! empty ( $_POST["agreement_one"])) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, "Agreement One", $_POST["agreement_one"] );
  }
  if ( ! empty ( $_POST["agreement_two"])) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, "Agreement Two", $_POST["agreement_two"] );
  }
  if ( ! empty ( $_POST["agreement_three"])) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, "Agreement Three", $_POST["agreement_three"] );
  }
}
```

It prints the error correctly if there are other fields which are also incorrect. The trouble comes when only the custom fields are empty. The errors don't stop the order from completing.

Am I missing something? Are my Hooks right?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Good catch. Updating now.

Comment: What do you mean by "The trouble comes when only the custom fields are empty" ? I have test your code on a test server and I don't really see what is your problem. For me It's working has expected. if another required field is empty, the form is not validated and i get an error message. If all the 3 checkboxes are not enabled by customer, same thing...

Comment: I'm using a Stripe plugin for transactions. When I click on the button to pay, a modal pops up to accept the credit card information. If I don't have the name, address, etc fields in the billing section the modal doesn't pop up and all the errors register. If I fill in all the billing info but leave the 3 required checkboxes empty, the modal appears as if everything is fine.

Comment: I think that you have certainly a javascript for this plugin, and is not checking your 3 custom fields. But with the material (code) of your question, is not possible to help more than that. So try to check for some js script in your plugin files, that is checking the fields… The problem comes from this plugin that is not taking care of that 3 custom fields. So maybe you can chose another option for your plugin process (Not a modal lightbox)…